# bidirectional match on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, nosql

I've indexed a list of terms and now I want to query for some of them

Say that I've indexed `'dog food','red dog','dog','food','cats'`

How do I create an exact bidirectional match query. ie: I want when search for 'dog' to get **only** the term `dog` and not the other terms (because they don't match back).

---

*One primitive solution I thought of is indexing the terms with their length (Words-wise) and then when searching query with lengh X restrict it to the terms of length X. but it seems over complicated.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom analyzer to lowercase and normalize your search terms. So that would be your index:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "my_analyzer_keyword" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "keyword",
          "filter" : [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "your_type" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "my_analyzer_keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So if you have indexed `'dog'` and users types in `Dog` or `dog` or `DOG`, it will match only `dog`, `'dog food'` won't be brought back.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your field's `index` property to `not_analyzed` and your query should use `term` filter to search for text.

As per Evaldas' suggestion, find below a more complete solution, that also keeps the original value indexed with `standard` analyzer but uses a sub-field with a lowercased version of the terms:

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "asset": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "case_ignore": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test/asset/1
{
  "name":"dog"
}
POST /test/asset/2
{
  "name":"dog food"
}
POST /test/asset/3
{
  "name":"red dog"
}

GET /test/asset/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name.case_ignore": "Dog"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't do that. In case of capital letters.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I'm not seeing any capital letters in the OP ;-).

Comment: Store-wise yes. But user can type anything! :)